# matplotlib: how to control custom grid linestyles for all plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to define a custom grid linestyle for my plots. I know that for any plot I can use `ax.grid(b=True, dashes=[6,2,1,2])` which works perfectly as expected for that axis. How can I set this linestyle for *all* my plots? There is no key in `matplotlib.rcParams` to control it with a matplotlibrc file (`rcParams['grid.linestyle'] = [6, 2, 1, 2]` does not work). I couldn't find any option in seaborn to control this with a custom style, either.

Is there a way to define a linestyle for all my plots without writing my own plot function (or decorator) as a wrapper?

Answer (score 2):

It works for me:

```py
plt.rcParams["grid.linestyle"]="dashed"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use your own style sheet? I think setting style is what you need. See [Customizing plots with style sheets](http://matplotlib.org/users/style_sheets.html) for more details.

Comment: Style sheets (like seaborn) are fundamentally rcParam based, so if there is no rcParam for the default grid dash pattern, they're not going to be helpful.